# Is $< enumerable

Tags: ruby, predefined-variables

`$<` is used with `map` in the following code.

Is `$<` enumerable?

```
$<.map{|l|p (0..9).to_a.repeated_permutation(4).count{|m|m.inject(&:+)==l.to_i}}
```

Comment: obviously: `$<.kind_of? Enumerable #=> true`

Comment: and `$<.class.ancestors #=> [ARGF.class, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's an alias of [`ARGF`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/ARGF.html) which inherits directly from `Object` and includes `Enumerable`.